# How to select a option from html table and submit the info into another page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql

I am making a website that books flights. I want to create a page which shows all the journey details (e.g: From: Bristol leave at: 08:00 To: Newcastle arrive at : 12:00 Fares: 50.......) from the table I created in phpmyadmin. I am able to show the table on the page but don't know how select one specific journey route and post this values to another page which prints out the info in a professional way. Any help?

Languages I am allowed to use Python, Javascript, HTML, SQL.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code.

Answer (score -2):

It's a good practice to have "id" column in your table, then you can select individual rows by id and show them. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    journey_details varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

"AUTO_INCREMENT" is needed so when you insert rows in your table the id of each row is incremented automatically.

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp